What made Moses strike the rock in Numbers 20?
We read in Numbers 20 how the itinerant Israelites run out of water.
Moses takes up the matter with God and is given the following instructions:

Take the staff, and you and your brother Aaron gather the assembly together. Speak to that rock before their eyes and it will pour out its water. You will bring water out of the rock for the community so they and their livestock can drink. (Numbers 20:8)

We then see Moses going out of the Tent, rebuking the Israelites and striking the rock with the staff as against God's instruction to speak to it. The rock does produce water, but the Lord is angry with Moses for the lack of trust. (On an earlier occasion, Moses was indeed asked to strike the rock while  Israel was camping at Rephidim, cf Exodus 17).
What made Moses act against God's instructions? Did he have in mind the Rephidim episode? Was he agitated at Israel's mistrust on  his leadership and lost his temper for a moment? Or, did he think that the dry rock was not going to produce water for the thankless people - whether he spoke to it or struck it? How do Bible scholars explain the seemingly impulsive behaviour of Moses? Are there any apocryphal writings available in the topic?

The question isn't exactly a duplicate, but some of the answers here may be informative.

Thanks, user111403. That question is on why God was ' so upset' . I would be the last one to question God's Wisdom. The answers given, however, are enlightening in as much as they try to ' nail' Moses . I hope for some different perspectives, especially because many Users have since joined CSE.  Hence the question. First and foremost , the possibility of the two rock water events being one and the same, needs to be ruled out.

Thanks, GratefulDisciple, for editing the question. I have since made a small correction in the Title.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/80233/why-did-god-still-allow-water-to-flow-from-the-rock-in-numbers-20-even-though-mo?rq=1

The following Q. was asked by me last October, which involved Numbers 20, resulting in some quality answers that I feel go along way in answering your Q. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/87193/why-exactly-were-aaron-and-miriam-denied-entrance-into-the-promised-land-in-ad

Anger and frustration:

Numbers 20:10 - And Moses and Aaron gathered the assembly
together before the rock; and he said to them, “Hear now, you
rebels! Must we bring water for you out of this rock?”

It sure looks like Moses is frustrated! The Israelites had been complaining and rebelling against Moses’ leadership for a long time by now, and this constant pressure may have led Moses to lose his temper.

One thing peculiar to Moses is his anger. Many times in the Bible has
his anger featured.
Exodus 32:19 “When Moses approached the camp and saw the calf and the
dancing, his anger burned and he threw the tablets out of his hands,
breaking them to pieces at the foot of the mountain.” [1]

Complaints had a large role to play in this:

This is exactly one reason why Moses gets angry all the time. Not only
did the people of Israel like to complain but they also disobey God
and have a rebellious heart. This part of the people’s behavior can
create frustration and then anger. The people of Israel are always
complaining even after seeing an evident miracle. They still refused
to believe that God could help them get through whatever stage they
find themselves in. [1]

Repetition:
Notice something that had happened previously:

Exodus 17:5-6 - And the Lord said to Moses, “Go on before the people,
and take with you some of the elders of Israel. Also take in your
hand your rod with which you struck the river, and go. 6 Behold, I
will stand before you there on the rock in Horeb; and you shall
strike the rock, and water will come out of it, that the people may
drink.”
And Moses did so in the sight of the elders of Israel.


Moses might have been influenced by the previous incident at Rephidim, where God had instructed him to strike the rock to bring forth water. It had been successful previously, right? So, Moses might have thought that the same action was required again, despite God’s different instructions this time.
Symbolic:

New Testament Scripture in 1 Corinthians teaches that the rock in the
desert was intended by God to be a picture of His Son, Jesus Christ: [2]


1 Corinthians 10:4 - and all drank the same spiritual drink. For they
drank of that spiritual Rock that followed them, and that Rock was
Christ.

Striking the rock the first-time symbolized Christ’s sacrifice, but striking it again could be seen as a misrepresentation of the once and for all nature of Christ’s sacrifice

So the Lord intended Moses strike the rock in the desert only once in
the scene from Exodus 17, thus picturing Jesus sacrificed once to
bring us salvation. Later in Numbers 20, the Lord instructed Moses to
only speak to the rock to preserve the picture created in Exodus 17.
When Moses chose to strike the rock a second time instead, he
disrupted the picture created in Exodus 17. Had God allowed Moses'
mistake to go unchallenged, we would likely be confused by the
distorted picture, concluding it was necessary for Christ (i.e., the
rock) to be sacrificed (i.e., struck) repeatedly for our salvation. [2]

Faith issue:

Numbers 20:12 - Then the Lord spoke to Moses and Aaron, “Because you
did not believe Me, to hallow Me in the eyes of the children of
Israel, therefore you shall not bring this assembly into the land
which I have given them.”


For had you spoken to the rock and it had given forth [water], I would
have been sanctified in the eyes of the congregation. They would have
said, "If this rock, which neither speaks nor hears, and does not
require sustenance, fulfills the word of the Omnipresent, how much
more should we!" - [Midrash Aggadah] [3]

Rashi: Hitting Instead of Speaking
By striking the rock instead of speaking to it, Moses breached the trust that God had placed in him to follow His instructions precisely. This breach of trust was significant because it misrepresented God’s will to the people.

As mentioned above, Rashi’s commonly accepted explanation is that
Moses hit the rock when G‑d instructed him to speak to it. G‑d specifically wanted him to speak to the rock so the Jewish people would realize that if even an inanimate rock listens to the word of G‑d, how much more so should they. They would have been so inspired, they would never have sinned again. Moses disobeyed G‑d and hit the rock, and an opportunity to glorify G‑d was missed. Therefore he and
Aaron were punished.
The Rebbe expands on this explanation, that their sin was due to the
public nature of their infraction, saying that the reason the sin was
treated so severely was because it happened publicly. Although they
committed a minor infraction, Moses and Aaron were punished severely
because they desecrated G‑d’s name before the eyes of all. This
teaches us how seriously we should take the desecration of G‑d’s name
in public. 4

Moses’ actions failed to project God’s holiness and faithfulness. We are image bearers of God and so we must listen to what he has to say and follow through. Instead of demonstrating God’s power through a simple act of speaking to the rock, Moses’ actions suggested a need for force and anger, which was a misrepresentation of God’s nature.




References:





Editor in Chief & by Editor in Chief. (2019, September 27). Why moses struck the rock and why God punished him (Numbers 20:11). ConnectUS. https://connectusfund.org/why-moses-struck-the-rock



Staff, C. A. (2024, March 28). In numbers 20, why did Moses and Aaron sin when they struck the rock? Catholic Answers. https://www.catholic.com/qa/in-numbers-20-why-did-moses-and-aaron-sin-when-they-struck-the-rock



Why was Moses punished for striking the rock? - Verse By Verse Ministry International. (n.d.). https://versebyverseministry.org/bible-answers/why-was-moses-punished-for-striking-the-rock?locale=en



Bamidbar - Numbers - Chapter 20 (Parshah Chukat). (n.d.). https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9948/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-20.htm



Moses Strikes the Rock: The full story. (n.d.). https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3839434/jewish/Moses-Strikes-the-Rock-The-Full-Story.htm




Thanks, Jason_ for the well sourced answer. I have another point to suggest: God was angry because there was a breach of trust. Moses was inside the Tent when God spoke to him. Israelites were outside the Tent. Moses striking the rock made the Israelites believe that God had wanted that of Moses. Striking twice conveyed that he was angry. Moses being Gods messenger, that would translate that God himself was angry with Israel. That did create a bad image of God , signalling Moses' failure in projecting God's holiness before Israel.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Good suggestion. I've added a bit to my answer!

Thanks. Stay blessed.

One option you didn't list is "The Bible does not spell out why so we don't know"

Fallen Human Nature Moses was merely acting out a fatal flaw in his human nature: unrestrained anger!  From murder to destroying the Ten Commandments to smiting the Rock, Moses demonstrated the fact that all men need to deal with their fallen nature  by referring to  what Jesus called "the New Birth. " See similar question BH.SE #96291.

It was his momentary unbelief expressed in his impatient anger not trusting that God would ever lead his people into the land of promise.

It is generally thought that the sin of Moses, in which Aaron shared,
consisted in his striking the rock—and doing so twice—instead of
merely speaking to it, “and it shall give forth its water;” and also,
in the hasty and improper language which he used on the occasion:
“Hear now, ye rebels, must we fetch you water out of this rock?” But
it seems difficult to accept this view. On the one hand, we can
scarcely imagine that unbelief should have led Moses to strike, rather
than to speak to the rock, as if the former would have been more
efficacious than the latter. On the other hand, it seems strange that
Moses should have been directed to “take the rod,” if he were not to
have used it, the more so as this had been the Divinely sanctioned
mode of proceeding at Rephidim. Lastly, how, in that case, could Aaron
have been implicated in the sin of Moses? Of course, the striking the
rock twice was, as we read in Psalm 106:32, 33, evidence that they had
“angered” Moses, and that “his spirit was provoked.” This also showed
itself in his language, which Scripture thus characterises: “he spake
unadvisedly with his lips”—or, as the word literally means, “he
babbled.” Be it observed, that Moses is not anywhere in Scripture
blamed for striking instead of speaking to the rock, while it is
expressly stated that the people “angered him also at the waters of
strife, so that it went ill with Moses for their sakes.”
The other aspect of the sin of Moses was afterwards expressly stated
by the Lord Himself, when He pronounced on Moses and Aaron the
sentence that they should not “bring this congregation into the land,”
which He had given them, on this ground: “Because ye believed Me not,
to sanctify Me in the eyes of the children of Israel” (20:12). Thus in
their rebellion against Moses and Aaron, the people had not believed
that Jehovah would bring them into the land which He had given them;
while, in their anger at the people, Moses and Aaron had not believed
God, to sanctify Him in His power and grace in the eyes of the
children of Israel. Israel failed as the people of God; Moses as their
mediator. Hitherto Moses had, under every provocation, been faithful
as a steward over his charge, and pleaded with God and prevailed,
because he believed. Now for the first time Moses failed, as we all
fail, through unbelief, looking at the sin of the people, and thence
inferring the impossibility of their inheriting the promises, instead
of looking at the grace and power of God which made all things
possible, and at the certainty of the promise. Unlike Abraham in
similar circumstances, “he staggered at the promises.” And having
through unbelief failed as mediator of the people, his office was to
cease, and the conduct of Israel into the land to devolve upon
another.
Edersheim, A. (1876). The Exodus and the Wanderings in the Wilderness
(pp. 186–188). Fleming H. Revell.

In addition this failure of Moses was a perfect representation of the law, his staff, that would in the future strike Christ into death.  By the law the inheritance of the promise could never have been entered into anyway but only by faith in the promise.
It is easy to believe in the Law and is natural to do so. In fact it is almost impossible not to believe the law even among unbelievers. But the gospel is very hard to believe and those who believe it have great difficulty believing in the gospel their whole lives without losing patience in themselves and others who seem not to take it seriously.  It is the yeast of the Pharisees, unbelief, as soon as we curse all the Christians for not being as holy as our standards will require we do fall, imagining that God does not still offer his grace in the same freshness as we once rejoined in.

Given that in Numbers 12:3 Moses is stated to be "very meek, above all the men which were upon the face of the earth" (K.J.V.), and in verses 7 & 8 God rebuked those who criticised him, saying "he is faithful in all mine house", demanding to know why his critics were not afraid to speak against him, then this question needs to be handled carefully.
A few chapters on comes the burial of his sister, Miriam. The year is not stated but these study Bible notes inform us:

"...this chapter [20] begins in the 40th year after the exodus. Most
of the people 20 years old or more at the time of the rebellion of
Kadesh would already have died... But their circuits [during that
time] would bring them back to the central camp at Kadesh, the scene
of their great rebellion. They have now come full circle; the land of
promise lies before them.
...Now, 40 years later, at the place of Israel's worst acts of
rebellion, the scene was recurring. The children of the rebellious
nation now desire to die with their parents; the complaints about the
bread from heaven are repeated by the sons.
Moses was told to take his staff, through which God had performed
wonders in Egypt and in the desert all these years, but this time he
was merely to speak to the rock and it would pour out its water for
the people. Cf. Ps 114:8
'Listen, you rebels' At once the accumulated anger, exasperation and frustration of 40 years came to expression. (See Ps 106:33). NIV Study
Bible pp. 216-7 footnotes, 1987 edition
"And they cause wrath by the waters of Meribah, and it is evil to
Moses for their sakes, for they have provoked his spirit, and he
speaketh wrongfully with his lips." Psalm 106:32-33 Y.L.T.

The N.I.V. Study Bible notes go on to suggest that the clear nature of Moses' offence is not clearly stated in this text, but Moses' disobeying God's plain instruction to merely speak to the rock could have indicated a lack of trust in God, as though he believed that a word alone would not suffice. Also, that God's holiness was offended by Moses' rash action, for he had not shown proper deference to God's presence.
That, really, is as much as the actual text permits. Later on we learn that the rock in the wilderness was actually Christ, but the question does not ask explanations about that, so that is much as I will say, merely to supplement an already excellent answer that gives explanations from Hebraic scholars.


Was he agitated at Israel's mistrust in his leadership and lost his temper for a moment?

This seems to be the most likely explanation. The text states that Moses was supposed to  "have confidence in me, to acknowledge my holiness before the Israelites." (vs 12) Whether he was supposed speak to the rock or strike it only once, the key failure was losing his temper at a crucial moment. Rather than upholding God's holiness and giving the people hope, he allowed his anger with the people to dominate him. God wanted to bless his people with water and give them confidence to march into Canaan. When Moses said "Hear now, you rebels! Are we to produce water for you out of this rock?” he did not honor God, but spoke from his own viewpoint. He then struck the rock in anger instead of approaching it with reverence for God.
We should also not overlook the fact that at the beginning of the chapter, Miriam's death is recorded. Immediately after this, we are told that there was no water. The loss of his beloved sister - she who had saved his life when Pharaoh sought to kill him and was the leader of the Israelite women during the Exodus - is probably another factor in Moses' lack of confidence in the Lord at this point.

Moses had been angry before, what made this time worse than the others? Exodus 32:19 And it came about, as soon as Moses approached the camp, that he saw the calf and the people dancing; and Moses’ anger burned, and he threw the tablets from his hands and shattered them to pieces at the foot of the mountain.

"Whether he was supposed speak to the rock or strike it only once" The Bible is clear on what God's instruction was. Numbers 20: 8 “Take the staff, and assemble the congregation, you and Aaron your brother, and tell the rock before their eyes to yield its water. So you shall bring water out of the rock for them and give drink to the congregation and their cattle.”

David D, striking someone or something once comes from one mental disposition whereas striking twice comes from anotherdisposition.For instance, a parent who spanks his child as a penalty for some wrong doing may spank once: but a parent who is in a foul mood after quarreling with the spouse, may spank the child twice for the very same mistake . Many a time we ventillate our personal grievances on our subordinates.

@DavidD ... see Ex. 17:6 for God's instruction to strike the rock (once, as I think in this case).  As to why losing his anger was so important, I think the other cases were also important but this one came at the end of the 40 years in the wilderness at a moment when God wanted Moses to act has his representative to give sustenance and courage to conquer Canaan.

@DanFefferman it had been Moses job to act as God's representative starting from the burning bush.
